# How to convert Doc/Docx into a single XML file automatically?

Tags: xml, ms-office, openxml, office-interop, docx

When you open up Word, it allows you to save as Word Open XML format. I've seen posts regarding opening up the docx file as a zip and then extracting stuff from there. But what I really want is a way to turn the docx into a single XML exactly like when doing the "save as" action in MS Office. What to do?

And how to do this for the .doc format ?

Note: I would like to do this programmatically.  Preferably under Linux development conditions with PHP. But if that's not available, then other languages will do. Lastly, if it comes down to it, I can consider spinning up a Windows server to do this.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry to resuscitate a dead thread, but I just found an answer for the DOCX files. A DOCX file is just a ZIP archive of XML files. So for extracting the contents of one of its file, v.gr. word/document.xml under a Linux environment, you have to run unzip:

```
unzip -q -c myfile.docx word/document.xml
```

For catching the output of this command into the $xml variable of a PHP script, you can issue:

```
$xml = shell_exec ("unzip -q -c myfile.docx word/document.xml");
```

Hoping this answer helps for DOCX files. Better late than never.

For DOC files, this method does not work.

Comment: I am trying to execute this code, but it's not working.. what am I missing?

Comment: Check the command unzip is present on your system. For which OS are you coding?

Comment: I was trying on windows although my actual server is Linux.
However I used ZipArchieve so my problem is solved for now, regarding this code I was not able to execute on windows.

Comment: You still can install some unzip utility on Windows: see http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/unzip.htm. If you want ot use the code above on a Windows machine, you will also havo to install php.

Answer (score 3):

Eric White explains how to do this for docx in C# at [transforming-open-xml-documents-to-flat-opc-format](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/transforming-open-xml-documents-to-flat-opc-format.aspx)

You can also do it using docx4j (which I work on), the 'j' being Java.

Answer (score 2):

In Word: file | save as | Word XML Document (*.xml) gives you the Open XML Format you want, as a single  XML file

In code using Interop: use Document object's SaveAs method, using WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument as the save format. You should also use the Document.Convert method to update the compatibility to the MS Office version installed.

So, not necessarily a complete demo, but this should give you the right idea:

```
ActiveDocument.Convert();

WdSaveFormat myNewSaveFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument;
ActiveDocument.SaveAs(newFilePath, myNewSaveFormat); //where newFilePath can be a FileInfo object specifying the new file name and extension (docx)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without interop? For example, the zip package that is the docx--does it have some sort of pattern that can be used to merge together something exactly the same as the single-file XML?

Comment: Sorry, it was tagged office-interop, so I assumed. Also, not sure if you'll be able to use Interop in a server scenario, might want to check other threads about that. || It sounds like you want each package/part which makes up a WordprocessingDocument object, however all in one unified package/part.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was trying to use wdFormatOpenDocumentText to save a .docx and was getting a COM Exception.